# UI using client handler to enable elements based on checkbox value

Tags: google-apps-script

So I want to enable or disable a datebox based on the value of a checkbox after a click. I can do it on the server side, as shown below, but can't seem to figure out how to make this work on the client side. My problem is I can't seem to access the value of the check box on without a call to the server. Any ideas?

```
var chkPaid = app.createCheckBox("Paid in Full").setName("paidInFull").setId("paidInFull");
var dateBox2 = app.createDateBox().setName("paidThrough").setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.DATE_MEDIUM).setEnabled(false).setId("paidThru");
var paidThruDisable = app.createServerHandler("disableHandler");
paidThruDisable.addCallbackElement(chkPaid);
chkPaid.addValueChangeHandler(paidThruDisable);
```

---

```
function disableHandler(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var widget = app.getElementById("paidThru");
  if(e.parameter.paidInFull !== "true"){
    widget.setEnabled(false);
  }else{
    widget.setEnabled(true);
  };
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a piece of code I wrote that does the trick ;-)

You can test it online [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyeEtioOOI2DuqEKh590M-YyNA2eWYei9HpykRwIZL2bzE7WcFE/exec)

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication()
  var chkPaida = app.createCheckBox("Paid in Full").setValue(true);
  var chkPaidb = app.createCheckBox("Paid in Full").setVisible(false);
  var checkpanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().add(chkPaida).add(chkPaidb)
  var dateBox2 = app.createDateBox().setName("paidThrough").setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.DATE_MEDIUM).setId("paidThru").setName("paidThru");

  var Chandlera = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(dateBox2).setEnabled(false).forTargets(chkPaidb).setVisible(true).setValue(false)
  .forEventSource().setVisible(false)  
  chkPaida.addClickHandler(Chandlera)

  var Chandlerb = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(dateBox2).setEnabled(true).forTargets(chkPaida).setVisible(true).setValue(true)
  .forEventSource().setVisible(false)  
  chkPaidb.addClickHandler(Chandlerb)

app.add(checkpanel).add(dateBox2)
  return app
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see what you did there. The problem is I only want one check box and when it is "unchecked" the box is no longer enabled.
Edit: Scratch that. That does the trick. I saw this code earlier and just assumed it was two visible checkboxes. I just need to remember to grab the value of only the visible one.

Comment: Invisibility!   Thanks to Henrique on this forum earlier this year and a little thank to Harry Potter as well :-)